# How to set JMS Header in spring integration message

Tags: java, java-8, jms, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to set jms correlation id in spring integration message by setting in its header before pushing into a IBM MQ but the value Is not available after reading the message from the queue.

Using the below code to set the header

```
MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hi")
.setHeader(JmsConstans.JMS_CORRELATIONID,"ID12334556889").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what is that `JmsConstans.JMS_CORRELATIONID`: it is not available in my dependencies. So, sounds more like it is your own and, therefore, we have to know its value.

The logic in the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` (used by default by the `JmsSendingMessageHandler`) is like this:

```
private void populateCorrelationIdPropertyFromHeaders(MessageHeaders headers, javax.jms.Message jmsMessage) {
    Object jmsCorrelationId = headers.get(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID);
    if (jmsCorrelationId instanceof Number) {
        jmsCorrelationId = jmsCorrelationId.toString();
    }
    if (jmsCorrelationId instanceof String) {
        try {
            jmsMessage.setJMSCorrelationID((String) jmsCorrelationId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.info("Failed to set JMSCorrelationID, skipping", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

where that `JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID` has this value: `jms_correlationId`.

However all of this is just a speculation since e don't know how you push that message to IBM MQ...